# FileSystemWatcher skips some events

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

If you google for `FileSystemWatcher` issues, you will find a lot of articles about `FileSystemWatcher` skipping some events (not firing all events). Basically, if you change a lot of files in watched folder some of them will not be processes by `FileSystemWatcher`.

Why is that so, and how can I avoid missing events?

Comment: It does not skip events.  Not writing an event handler for the Error event is your mistake.  There is no other way to find out that your event handlers are too slow and/or that you need to increase InternalBufferSize.  Also nothing it can do about you using try/catch in the event handlers to ignore the IOException that tells you that you can't open the file yet.

Comment: Of course that you need a error event handler. My code only demonstrates the separation of file change detection and file processing in two threads. Also I didn't wrote a code that would detect whether a file has been released by process that created it. That code should be in ProcessFile function as I commented in code.

Answer (score 13):

### Cause

`FileSystemWatcher` is watching for changes happening in some folder. When file is changed (e.g. file is created), the `FileSystemWatcher` raises the appropriate event. The event handler might unzip the file, read its content to decide how to process it further, write record of it in database log table and move the file to another folder. The processing of the file might take some time.

During that time another file might be created in watched folder. Since `FileSystemWatcher`’s event handler is processing the first file, it cannot handle creation event of second file. So, the second file is missed by `FileSystemWatcher`.
[image]

### Solution

Since file processing might take some time and creation of other files might get undetected by `FileSystemWatcher`, file processing should be separated from file change detection and file change detection should be so short that it never misses single file change. File handling can be divided into two threads: one for the file change detection and the other for the file processing. When file is changed and it is detected by `FileSystemWatcher`, appropriate event handler should only read its path, forward it to file processing thread and close itself so `FileSystemWatcher` can detect another file change and use the same event handler. The processing thread could take as much time as it needs to process the file. A queue is used for forwarding file path from event handler thread to the processing thread.
[image]

This is classic producer-consumer problem. More about producer-consumer queue can be found [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_WaitHandle_Producer_Consumer_Queue).

### Code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FileSystemWatcherExample {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // If a directory and filter are not specified, exit program
            if (args.Length !=2) {
                // Display the proper way to call the program
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe \"directory\" \"filter\"");
                return;
            }

            FileProcessor fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();

            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher
            FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher1 = new FileSystemWatcher();

            // Set FileSystemWatcher's properties
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = args[0];
            fileSystemWatcher1.Filter = args[1];
            fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

            // Add event handlers
            fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_Created);

            // Start to watch
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the program.");
            while(Console.Read()!='q');

            // Turn off FileSystemWatcher
            if (fileSystemWatcher1 != null) {
                fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                fileSystemWatcher1.Dispose();
                fileSystemWatcher1 = null;
            }

            // Dispose fileProcessor
            if (fileProcessor != null)
                fileProcessor.Dispose();
        }

        // Define the event handler
        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            // If file is created...
            if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created) {
                // ...enqueue it's file name so it can be processed...
                fileProcessor.EnqueueFileName(e.FullPath);
            }
            // ...and immediately finish event handler
        }
    }


    // File processor class
    class FileProcessor : IDisposable {
        // Create an AutoResetEvent EventWaitHandle
        private EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private Thread worker;
        private readonly object locker = new object();
        private Queue<string> fileNamesQueue = new Queue<string>();

        public FileProcessor() {
            // Create worker thread
            worker = new Thread(Work);
            // Start worker thread
            worker.Start();
        }

        public void EnqueueFileName(string FileName) {
            // Enqueue the file name
            // This statement is secured by lock to prevent other thread to mess with queue while enqueuing file name
            lock (locker) fileNamesQueue.Enqueue(FileName);
            // Signal worker that file name is enqueued and that it can be processed
            eventWaitHandle.Set();
        }

        private void Work() {
            while (true) {
                string fileName = null;

                // Dequeue the file name
                lock (locker)
                    if (fileNamesQueue.Count > 0) {
                        fileName = fileNamesQueue.Dequeue();
                        // If file name is null then stop worker thread
                        if (fileName == null) return;
                    }

                if (fileName != null) {
                    // Process file
                    ProcessFile(fileName);
                } else {
                    // No more file names - wait for a signal
                    eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        }

        private ProcessFile(string FileName) {
            // Maybe it has to wait for file to stop being used by process that created it before it can continue
            // Unzip file
            // Read its content
            // Log file data to database
            // Move file to archive folder
        }


        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose() {
            // Signal the FileProcessor to exit
            EnqueueFileName(null);
            // Wait for the FileProcessor's thread to finish
            worker.Join();
            // Release any OS resources
            eventWaitHandle.Close();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Here's where it's documented about losing changes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_6 . "The Windows operating system notifies your component of file changes in a buffer created by the FileSystemWatcher. If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow. This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory, and it will only provide blanket notification."

Comment: I suspect for most use cases, this code should prevent that internal buffer from overflowing.  As long as the event handler can process the events faster than they are being fed, the internal buffer should never overflow.

Comment: Eric J. is right. This solution is not for cases when you have many changes in short period of time so buffer overflows. This is for cases in which time between changes of two files is shorter then time of processing a first file. During processing of first file a second is changed so event handler cannot process it. If FSW watched a lot of changes in long period of time you will certainly have this problem.

Comment: why does something gets lost and not queued, that does not make any sense to me. V8 does also not simply discard events when it is busy?

Comment: It gets queued in the buffer, but the buffer is small and may overflow when there are hundreds of events in a short time while the eventhandler is running. Event handler block the object which raise the event.