# filesystemwatcher waiting for file to complete writing

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have an issue with a file system watcher application I am working on. It seems to run fine with a single file but not with multiple files or a folder with files inside.

in the code below, I call IsFileReady to determine if the file has completed writing before trying to copy it to the other folder. However, when a new folder is created with files inside, for some reason it's hanging and not continuing.

I think it's because multiple files are being written at the same time and my code is referencing just a single file, but I am unsure of how to correct this.

Any assistance is appreciated and thank you.

```
static void Init()
    {
        string directory = watch_path;
        Program._watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory);
        Program._watcher.Created +=
            new FileSystemEventHandler(Program._watcher_Changed);
        Program._watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Program._watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    }

    static void _watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CHANGED, NAME: " + e.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("CHANGED, FULLPATH: " + e.FullPath);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checking If File Exists at copy location");
            if (!File.Exists(copy_path + "\\" + e.Name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for File to complete write");
                WaitForFile(e.FullPath);
                Console.WriteLine("Copying file to remote folder");
                File.Copy(e.FullPath, copy_path + "\\" + e.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Copy Completed writing to log");
                error_handling("File Copy Completed : ", copy_path + "\\" + e.Name, e.FullPath);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Copy Failed Writing to Log");
                error_handling("File Copy Skipped, File exists at destination : ", copy_path + "\\" + e.Name, e.FullPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Copy process totally failed" + error.Message);
            error_handling("File Copy Failed ", "Exception: " + error.Message, "00");
        }
    }

    public static void WaitForFile(string filename)
    {
        while (!IsFileReady(filename)) { }
    }

    public static bool IsFileReady(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                return inputStream.Length > 0;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

*Edit

1. When it hangs, it seems that the WaitForFile never actually finishes up. When copying a single file, it finishes no problem, but I think when there are multiple files it get stuck somehow and it will not go past the

   ```
   WaitForFile(e.FullPath);
   ```
2. I am intentionally hooking the Created event. the use of this application is to monitor a folder that needs to be identical between multiple web servers. the sync process needs to be as fast as possible as the web servers are load balanced.
3. the Call to error_handling is just a write to log function as seen below:

   ```
   public static void error_handling(string message, string fileident, string source)
   {
       using (System.IO.StreamWriter myFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(log_folder + "\\" + log_file, true))
       {
           string finalMessage = string.Format("{0}: {1} SOURCE: {3} - DEST: {2}", DateTime.Now, message, fileident, source, Environment.NewLine);
           myFile.WriteLine(finalMessage);
           myFile.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You mention the code hangs at a certain point. What line does it hang on and is it consistently the same line over multiple runs?

Comment: A couple of other notes - are you intentionally only hooking the Created event on the watcher (you don't care about changed/deleted/renamed?). What does the call to error_handling do?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer your replies

Comment: Here are a couple of links that will help, however, introducing threading is a big leap and if you're unfamiliar with it, it will very likely cause even stranger behavior that will have you pulling your hair out. If you do go that path, one note is that the StreamWriter you're using in your error_handling method is not thread safe. Also, for what you are trying to accomplish, especially if it is for commercial/production use, I highly recommend buying a product that does exactly what you need (they do exist).

Comment: The links I mentioned above: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59385/filesystemwatcher-with-threaded-fifo-processing   and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048619/filesystemwatcher-skips-some-events

Comment: Subscribing the Error event is important.  It is quite likely to fire in this code, the Changed event handler takes too long.